How to print out a function's inputs when creating a function factory with purrr::partial()
I'm playing around with purrr's map() and partial() and want to try and create a list of functions with pre-configured inputs and when I use those function it will return the functions output AND print out the function's configuration (also as a validation check to make sure I've correct configured the function)
I've set up each function with pre-configured inputs without any problem but I cant get it to message the inputs.
library(tidyverse)

#arbitrary sequence

n_vec <- seq(5,100,5)
mean_vec <- seq(50,1000,50)

# create list of functions that are pre-configured with various inputs

rnorm_lst <- map2(
  .x=n_vec
  ,.y=mean_vec
  ,.f=\(.x,.y){

# When I use a function, I want it to message its input assumptions

    print(.x)
    print(.y)
    
# this is the underlying function that I want to create with partial
   out <-  partial(rnorm,n=.x,mean=.y)
   
   return(out)
   
  }
)

# create a name based on its configuration
names_lst <- paste0("n",n_vec,"_","mean",mean_vec)

# assign a name to each function

names(rnorm_lst) <- names_lst

# call a function to see if it works

rnorm_lst$n50_mean500()


The rnorm() aspect of this works but its not printing or messaging its inputs.
I think it has to do with the environment it is? but I'm not sure.

The print(.x) and print(.y) are being executed during the definition of rnorm_list, not during the execution of the functions.
I moved the print()s into the definition of a new function which I then fed into partial():
library(purrr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'purrr'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     %||%

n_vec <- seq(5,100,5)
mean_vec <- seq(50,1000,50)

# create list of functions that are pre-configured with various inputs

rnorm_lst <- map2(
                  .x=n_vec
                  ,.y=mean_vec
                  ,.f=\(.x,.y){

                      # this is the underlying function that I want to create with partial
                      new <-  function(...) {
                          # When I use a function, I want it to message its input assumptions

                          print(.x)
                          print(.y)

                          rnorm(...) 
                      }

                      return(partial(new, n = .x, mean = .y))
                  }
)

# create a name based on its configuration
names_lst <- paste0("n",n_vec,"_","mean",mean_vec)

# assign a name to each function

names(rnorm_lst) <- names_lst

# call a function to see if it works

rnorm_lst$n50_mean500()
#> [1] 50
#> [1] 500
#>  [1] 499.7868 500.5834 500.0835 500.7119 500.0949 498.2750 498.4815 498.7130
#>  [9] 499.7779 500.8300 500.8086 498.2535 500.4854 498.6614 501.3506 501.5732
#> [17] 500.3742 500.5254 499.3777 498.4927 499.7738 500.9925 499.4880 499.0919
#> [25] 500.4387 499.7716 500.7130 498.2386 500.1190 499.8829 499.2836 499.4103
#> [33] 499.5191 499.9471 499.8817 500.2749 499.9995 499.4147 500.4018 498.9776
#> [41] 499.6448 500.0447 500.4869 500.0282 499.4247 500.2372 500.5241 500.1198
#> [49] 500.4847 500.1996

Created on 2024-05-19 with reprex v2.1.0
